# GTA 4 will not progress past loading on Steam

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

I have had the game for awhile, I can get it started up, and I can see the main menu, but, when I hit play it just scrolls through the characters endlessly.

Is there any way to fix this problem?  Does anyone know what is causing it to happen?

Comment: We would need more information, including how long you've waited, a task manager confirmation to see if the program has stopped responding, and perhaps your system specs vs the minimum requirements to run the game.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out! Don't open it by Steam! Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\`, then open the GTAIV folder and run the launch .exe.